# Using service worker in a VM

Tags: javascript

As mentioned in the spec of service workers, it can be used only if the protocol is 'https' but i am using a VM for development in which url is of the form `http://myname.domainName.com:port` . Is there any way I can use it here ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add https support on your VM webserver.
Then create your own certificate authority and add it to the ones you trust. With this authority, you make a certificate for myname.domainName.com and use it on your webserver.
As you added the CA to your trusted ones, it'll work.